# Place Picker Closes On Search

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I have checked out a bunch of PlacePicker problems and they all seem to be with the API key. I don't think that this is my problem because I am able to successfully select places on the map that are nearby me, but once I hit the search button and hit any key the search closes.

Here is the PlacePicker code for my activity

```
 placeHeading = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.schools_list);
        placeHeading.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    getGeo();
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;

    public void getGeo() throws GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException, GooglePlayServicesRepairableException {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

        startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
                String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
                placeHeading.setText(place.getName());
                Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my manifest. The search function for my PlacePicker was working before until I started trying to integrate Firebase.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.Mac.xxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Kindly check the error logs and tell us what you're getting.